# How to Create Stored Procedures in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Select tblppmp.idn
,tblppmp.total_item as a_total 
,tblRequest.Quantity as b_total 
,tblppmp.total_item - tblRequest.Quantity as itemsleft 
FROM ppmp.dbo.tblppmp
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT
tblrequest.idn
,sum(tblRequest.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM ppmp.dbo.tblrequest 
WHERE tblrequest.dr_year = 2015
GROUP BY tblrequest.idn) tblrequest ON tblppmp.idn = tblrequest.idn
```

Above is my code, how to create stored procedure and the value of the dr_year may change depending on the textbox or  combobox selected by the user..sample is where tblrequest.dr_year = "Textbox1.text"

Comment: Where is the TextBox? Is this a VB application, ASP.NET?

Comment: Vb sir.. visual basic 2008

Comment: sir? are you there?

Answer (score 1):

Whether the different value comes from a textbox or a combobox is irrelevant. It will always come into your stored procedure as a [SQL parameter](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/).

To create the Stored Procedure, simply execute the following on your database:

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetAddress
AS
SELECT * FROM Person.Address
GO
```

*Replace the database name "AdventureWorks" in the `USE` command and the procedure name "uspGetAddress" in the `CERATE PROCEDURE` command with your database and procedure names respectively*

Since you have a dynamic date value, you'll need to add the parameter. This changes your SQL code to look something more like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetAddress @Date datetime
AS
...
GO
```

[Check out MsSQLTips for more info](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/)

Comment: in LINQ SIR. HOW TO CREATE MY CODE IN LINQ?..I CANNOT MAKE MY CODE IN LINQ..I DONT KNOW HOW TO START WITH CODE..

Comment: Your question is wrong then. It specifically asked how to create a stored procedure but said nothing about linq. I'd suggest you ask a new question about how to convert that sql statement to a linq query.